# Resize Window

Tags: html

I have a html page. I want to make sure that if I resize the window, the contents also get resized so as not to get scrolled horizontally. What can I do?

Answer (score 7):

Don't use absolute widths and heights. Set all values to percentages instead. Thats pretty much all you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Minimize your use of static widths.  The browser will do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Look up liquid layouts in google.  You'll get lots of ideas, templates and sample CSS to use

Answer (score 2):

[Fluid Grids](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids) from [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) is a good example of how to design a fluid layout, even when using grids.

Avoid `px` and `pt` (and `cm`, `in`, `mm`, `pc` and `ex`) in CSS. Try to use `em` and `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid use of absolute values.

Eg: try to use width="50%" instead of width="167px"

Answer (score 0):

Besides many fluid layout techniques mentioned in other answers, there are [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) (and ["Switchy McLayout" script](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/switchymclayout/) that works in old browsers) that allow you to dynamically apply different CSS rules (even completely different layout) depending on screen resolution or window size.